# conditional statement ELEMENT that Contains jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a sample HTML like this:

```
<div class="item">
   <span class=itemlist>Soap</span>
    <br>Zest
    <br>Safeguard
    <br>Perla
</div>

<div class="item">
    <span class=itemlist>Detergents</span>
     <br>Tide
     <br>Surf
     <br>Ariel     
</div>
```

and this is my jQuery code that `.empty()` body contents and output the `DIV` contents that contains "Shoes" in the itemlist

```
var pro=$('.item .itemlist:contains(Shoes)');
output = pro.closest('.item')[0].outerHTML
$('body').empty();
$('<div>').attr("id","result").appendTo('body');
$("#result").html(output);
```

What i want is to create a conditional statement that checks if the `SPAN` itemlist `:contains` Shoes. If the requirement is not met then the body will be emptied and the `#result div` will gives an output like "No record is found". Else, the body will be emptied and it will output the record matches it criteria

if `.itemlist` `contains:` Shoes exists, then the output will be just like this:

```
<div class="item">
        <span class=itemlist>Shoes</span>
         <br>Zara
         <br>Adidas
         <br>Nike    
</div>
```

Comment: you there with us now?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: ok then.. ill make a fiddle for it :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m22M7/

Comment: i want a conditional statement for it.. if itemlist like Shoes does not exist on the span content then, it should output like: "No Record is Found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `length` property of the `$()` function's result to see if any elements were returned by the selector because `$()` returns an array of 0 or more jQuery items. This fixes your issue:

```
var pro=$('.item .itemlist:contains(Shoes)');
if(pro.length > 0)
{
    output = pro.closest('.item')[0].outerHTML
    $('body').empty();
    $('<div>').attr("id","result").appendTo('body');
    $("#result").html(output);
}
else
{
    $('body').html("<div>No records found</div>");
}
```

See a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sJ5WV/1/